# Logstash not running

Tags: logstash

I've a logstash instance, version 2.3.1 which isn't running using the command

```
sudo service logstash start
```

Whenever I run this command, it returns `logstash started` and after a few moments when I check the status, I find that logstash isn't running. Although, when I start the logstash from `opt` to get output on the terminal, it runs without any error.

Note that `logstash.err` and `logstash.stdout` files are empty and `logstash.log` file isn't anywhere to be found. I've also set `LS_GROUP` to `adm` in `init.d` which caused the same issue on another instance, but even that doesn't seem to work now. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On an Ubuntu system, this behavior can be seen by logstash. To get around it, you can change the logstash user group in `/etc/init.d/logstash` to `adm` which stands for admin and you're good to go.

Answer (score 0):

This is normal behaviour of Logstash.
Can you test if your Logstash instance is working correctly?

Windows:
Go to your bin folder of logstash
and type logstash

Linux:
Enter this command in the prompt (bin folder of your logstash instance)
/opt/logstash/bin/logstash

Both:
If you get No command given ... you're logstash instance has the correct setup.

You can always run your Logstash instance with this command

```
logstash -e 'input { stdin { } } output { stdout {} }'
```

After this you can enter some text values and they will output to your console.

If this all works you can be sure that your Logstash instance is running correctly.

You may ask yourself why is this? This is because Logstash waits to start untill it gets a config to run with or another option.

If you want to start Logstash automatically on startup. You need to use this command.

```
sudo update-rc.d logstash defaults 96 9
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually,you should read the guide of logstash.In the "getting started section",The official documentation has the corret way for you to start a logstash work.
First,you should write a configure file such as "std.conf",look like this:

```
input {
  stdin {
  }
}
output{
  stdout{
  codec=>rubydebug
  }
}
```

Then,start your logstash:

```
bin/logstash -f conf/std.conf
```

If you want this work can run in the background(such as get some log files into elasticsearch),you may also need add "&" in the end of the command,like this:

```
bin/logstash -f conf/getlog.conf &
```

with this file(std.conf) and this command,your logstash will start up and if you type  any word in you terminal,it will print out in the terminal,like this:

```
{
   "message" => "hello",
  "@version" => "1",
"@timestamp" => "2016-08-06T19:47:36.543Z",
      "host" => "bag"
}
```

Now,you have got the normal operation of logstah,you may need more information,from there:[The official documentation of logstash](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/index.html)

Try this,and keep going,it`s easy for you~

Comment: It was just a change in logstash user group in init.d which did the trick. I've added an answer for future reference.

Comment: I may also not understand it,because in my case,I had never started the logstash like "sudo service logstash start",instead that, I start it with the command "bin/logstash -f conf/std.conf ".Would you please give me some reference about your actions;I will be very glad to learn it,thanks~

Comment: You can install logstash using the `.deb` file to use it as a service. This enables logging into `/var/log/logstash` which I prefer on live servers. You have to place the config file(s) in `/etc/logstash/conf.d` directory. The stdout and errors can be found in `/var/log/logstash` as well. You can also follow a tutorial by DigitalOcean on how to deploy ELK stack which achieves the same goal but without using a debian package.

Comment: @KeshavAgarwal  Thanks  ! I find that tutorial on DigitalOcean,it `s cool to use logstash as a server~